# How can I color a text?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, text-object

I did in Object Mode > Add > Text Now I want to change the text color to red. Now it's in gray.

[image: Blender text]

This is a screenshot of the text in red but how can I make that when I'm carving the text into the cube it will carve it with the text color and not the cube color ? Now the carved text still in gray and not in red :

You can see the left carved text is in gray and I want it to be in red :

[image: Carved text on cube is in gray. I want when carving the text into the cube that it will carved the text with the text color and not the cube color.]

Comment: Which color? You will need to assign material on your text, and change that material color.

Comment: @Hikariztw I found how to change th color of the text it self but now I want to change also the carved color on the cube. In fact I want that when I carve the text on the cube it will carve it with the text color. Now it even if the color is in red the carved text on the cube is still gray.

Comment: @Hikariztw Changing the color of the text was easy I went to the text material on the right and changed the color. But how can I make that when I carve it into the cube it will carve it with the text color ? The way I'm carving the text is moving the text close to the cube part of it inside the cube then selecting the cube and then adding modifier boolean then change to Difference and object set to text then Apply. But when moving the text the carved text on the cube is gray in the cube color and not from the text color.

Comment: @Hikariztw You can see in the screenshot the carved text on the cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mesh can't use a material which is not contained in slots.

I will try to guess what you have done so far. You **create a text**, make it thick enough, **turn it into mesh**. And for that wall, you use a **bool modifier with difference** operation, select the mesh text. And get no color?

#### 1) Make sure your text have an material on it

[image]

#### 2) In your wall object, you will need a same material in the slot

[image]

At the time you add the same material on the wall, you should see the text color in your wall.

[image]